# Discord Bot: Adding a role based on user_id with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to add a role to a user. I have only have their user id, so I need a way to get the `GuildMember` object with that info exclusively.

```
let member = // get member from id
 
member.roles.add('my role id')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have the User ID, you can use [`Guild.member()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=member):

```js
// <guild> is a placeholder for the guild object that has the role.
<guild>.member('ID')

member.roles.add(...)
```

Comment: how can i get guild?

Comment: If you want to use the guild the message was sent in, use `message.guild`. If you're not in a `message` event or want to get a different guild, use `client.guilds.cache.get('Guild ID Here')`